# Best way to backup user's inputs dealing with orientation changes

Tags: android, backup, fragment, orientation-changes

I am developing a simple apps that allow users to post articles on a website.

It's just a simple form with inputs for title et text and a send button.

To do this, I used a FragmentActivity with a Fragment called ArticleFragment inside.

I've read everywhere that the best way to save user's inputs was to override onPause() in the fragment, and to restore them in the onCreateView().

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Pausing fragment");
    Log.i(TAG, "Saving edits");

    // Sauvegarde des saisies
    EditText titreEdit = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.titre_saisie);
    EditText texteEdit = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.texte_saisie);
    String titre = titreEdit.getText().toString();
    String texte = texteEdit.getText().toString();

    SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
    Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("titre", titre);
    editor.putString("texte", texte);
    editor.commit();

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.article_enregistre, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

    super.onPause();
}
```

As you can see, each time the activity is paused, a Toast is shown to inform the user that inputs have been saved.

That's what I wanted. But whenever the user changes the orientation of the screen, the popup is shown again (because Activity is paused, then destroyed) and this may annoye the user.

I tried to add android:configChanges="orientation" in the Manifest, but I think this is not the best way to deal with this issue.

I also tried to make a solution with onSaveInstance() but I do not understand how it works : sometimes onSavedInstance is null, sometimes not.

With all this, the main question is what is the best way to save user inputs, with orientation changes and back button, and where to restore what was saved.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if input values are empty in onBackPressed() and onClick of whatever button that takes the user to Home and display appropriate Toast message

Comment: Because I would like to have the same behavior as the Messages app. When you type an SMS, and press back button it says "Draft saved", but when you change the screen orientation there is no toast!

Comment: Maybe you can than save it in a Bundle in onDestroy() and then check in onCreate() if Bundle is null

Comment: I don't quite follow your logic. Lets see ... You have two edittext fields and save button, when user changes screen orientation on destroy you can save input in shared preferences or in Bundle and when onCreate() starts you can check if values are not empty and then show toast that there is a draft. If user hits back button you can also save input and display toast, if he/she hits send you just send input, right ?

Comment: Yes but I don't want to show a Toast on screen orientation. Only if the user hits back button or home button.

Comment: Than check if values are empty in onBackPressed() and onClick of whatever button that is Home

Comment: That's what I thought. I wanted to do something more specific: without using android: configChanges, and without writing a backup function for each button.

Answer (score 0):

Add android:configChanges="orientation"to manifest file. 
Override onConfigurationChanged. Before you call super.onConfigurationChanged save the data.
If you have different layout files for portrait and landscape you have to remove all the views and setcontentview and initialize them(just like what you do on create ) after all these you can restore the data

Comment: Is this the best way? In this case, there will be a duplication of code.

Comment: Put all the saving data code in a function and call that in both places. You can avoid the code duplication.
If you dont want on pause to get called, AFAIK this is the best way

Comment: Thank's almuneef. I will try your solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite follow your logic. Lets see ... You have two edittext fields and save button, when user changes screen orientation on destroy you can save input in shared preferences or in Bundle and when onCreate() starts you can check if values are not empty and then show toast that there is a draft. If user hits back button you can also save input and display toast, if he/she hits send you just send input, right ?